# How to save figure in Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save my figure in Matplotlib to a file but when I run the command to save the image, it doesn't give any errors but I can't see the file.

```
plt.savefig('Traveling Salesmen Graph.png')
```

Comment: Please check for it in your current working directory

Comment: `plt.savefig()` goes before `plt.show()`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I don't have a plt.show() I just have a plt.plot()

Comment: Please provide a [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SpideyZac It might help to save the file to a specific location and check there. When I ran your command, the figure is saved to the working directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pyplot keeps track of the "current figure", and functions called on the library which require a figure operate on that, but you can also be more explicit by calling `savefig()` on the figure object.

as an example from https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-save-figure-to-image-file/:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = numbers')
plt.title('Legend inside')
ax.legend()
#plt.show()

fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

Being explicit in this way should solve your issue.

For references to pyplot functions which operate on the "current figure" see: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html

Comment: `plt.savefig` is very much a thing. This is not factually correct

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right, I've modified the answer.